# How to place Empathy in Gnome 3's messaging bar?

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell, empathy

For consistency between Skype and Empathy, I'd like to put Empathy into the bottom messaging bar in Gnome 3 (Gnome Shell, if you will). Is there a way to do this?

(I use Gnome 3.4, although answers for any version are welcome.)

Comment: On my system (Debian testing, GNOME 3.4), I can close the Empathy contact list window and remain available. Notifications appear in the message tray.

Comment: I know, that's what I'm trying to change. :)